# Xcode's mechanism blocks latest build on older version iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode

The Xcode 6.3.2 has the compatibility from iOS 4.3. I run an application built with minimum deployment target with 6.0 and I try to run this application in iPhone with iOS lower than 6.0. When we do this, Generally Xcode prompts and saying, targeted device doesn't have the support kind of error.

What mechanism that Xcode and iPhone has to prompt the user by saying this incompatibility message.

This question seems to be meaningless. But, Just Wanted to know how the Xcode doing this? and with what mechanism?

If anybody has idea. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you asking how Xcode determines that your app built for iOS 6 won't run on a device with iOS 5? Or are you asking why Xcode prevents you from trying?

Comment: @Caleb - I meant your first question "how"?

Comment: There's a key in your `info.plist` that sets the minimum OS version: `MinimumOSVersion`

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying through the app store, the user won't be able to install it. It won't even show up in the search results for them.

Comment: No, I just want to know the mechanism behind this scene. How the Xcode is doing?. I am not going to do any deployment. I think, this comment may describe my question.

Answer (score 0):

*It depends on the iphone ios version and the xcode  Deployement target you set no matter what the base SDK is..*
[image]